# Ubuntu 14.04 randomly freezes (DRM)

Tags: 14.04, intel-graphics

This random freeze has been happening for months now. I believe the problem is in the Direct Rendering Manager (DRM).

From kernel log:

```
dalius@PC1124:~$ cat /var/log/kern.log | grep drm
Sep  8 17:23:44 PC1124 kernel: [   25.515278] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
Sep  8 17:23:44 PC1124 kernel: [   26.027712] [drm] Memory usable by graphics device = 2048M
Sep  8 17:23:44 PC1124 kernel: [   26.027719] fb: conflicting fb hw usage inteldrmfb vs VESA VGA - removing generic driver
Sep  8 17:23:44 PC1124 kernel: [   26.072105] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
Sep  8 17:23:44 PC1124 kernel: [   26.072108] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
Sep  8 17:23:45 PC1124 kernel: [   26.190925] fbcon: inteldrmfb (fb0) is primary device
Sep  8 17:23:45 PC1124 kernel: [   26.265140] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
Sep  8 17:23:45 PC1124 kernel: [   26.265742] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20080730 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
Sep  8 18:21:25 PC1124 kernel: [ 3497.804013] [drm:i915_hangcheck_elapsed] *ERROR* Hangcheck timer elapsed... render ring idle
Sep  9 09:12:37 PC1124 kernel: [   36.280400] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
Sep  9 09:12:37 PC1124 kernel: [   36.535447] [drm] Memory usable by graphics device = 2048M
Sep  9 09:12:37 PC1124 kernel: [   36.535454] fb: conflicting fb hw usage inteldrmfb vs VESA VGA - removing generic driver
Sep  9 09:12:37 PC1124 kernel: [   36.592545] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
Sep  9 09:12:37 PC1124 kernel: [   36.592547] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
Sep  9 09:12:37 PC1124 kernel: [   36.711561] fbcon: inteldrmfb (fb0) is primary device
Sep  9 09:12:37 PC1124 kernel: [   36.789513] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
Sep  9 09:12:37 PC1124 kernel: [   36.791186] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20080730 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
Sep 10 09:11:10 PC1124 kernel: [   35.714929] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
Sep 10 09:11:10 PC1124 kernel: [   35.887189] [drm] Memory usable by graphics device = 2048M
Sep 10 09:11:10 PC1124 kernel: [   35.887199] fb: conflicting fb hw usage inteldrmfb vs VESA VGA - removing generic driver
Sep 10 09:11:10 PC1124 kernel: [   35.932129] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
Sep 10 09:11:10 PC1124 kernel: [   35.932131] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
Sep 10 09:11:10 PC1124 kernel: [   36.060649] fbcon: inteldrmfb (fb0) is primary device
Sep 10 09:11:10 PC1124 kernel: [   36.137382] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
Sep 10 09:11:10 PC1124 kernel: [   36.147893] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20080730 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
Sep 11 08:34:45 PC1124 kernel: [84264.804020] [drm:i915_hangcheck_elapsed] *ERROR* Hangcheck timer elapsed... render ring idle
Sep 11 09:07:46 PC1124 kernel: [   24.695604] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
Sep 11 09:07:47 PC1124 kernel: [   25.412141] [drm] Memory usable by graphics device = 2048M
Sep 11 09:07:47 PC1124 kernel: [   25.412150] fb: conflicting fb hw usage inteldrmfb vs VESA VGA - removing generic driver
Sep 11 09:07:47 PC1124 kernel: [   25.456089] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
Sep 11 09:07:47 PC1124 kernel: [   25.456092] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
Sep 11 09:07:47 PC1124 kernel: [   25.574852] fbcon: inteldrmfb (fb0) is primary device
Sep 11 09:07:47 PC1124 kernel: [   25.649351] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
Sep 11 09:07:47 PC1124 kernel: [   25.649523] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20080730 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
```

The freeze happens on these:

```
dalius@PC1124:~$ cat /var/log/kern.log | grep drm | grep hang
Sep  8 18:21:25 PC1124 kernel: [ 3497.804013] [drm:i915_hangcheck_elapsed] *ERROR* Hangcheck timer elapsed... render ring idle
Sep 11 08:34:45 PC1124 kernel: [84264.804020] [drm:i915_hangcheck_elapsed] *ERROR* Hangcheck timer elapsed... render ring idle
```

After this, I can't switch to tty1-tty6. I mostly see frozen login screen, but this has happened during normal usage (mostly while using alt+tab). Only solution is to hard reboot. I've found out about REISUB and will try it next time this happens.

Asus P5G41T-M LX2/GB (Integrated Intel GMA X4500 graphics)

Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU E3400

Full HW info: http://pastebin.com/JSuVy8CU

Any suggestions on how to resolve/further debug this issue appreciated.

Comment: I think I'm having the exact same issue with the same exact video+RAM configuration here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/659188/intel-x4500-8gb-ram-no-more-mtrrs-available-and-x-freeze  OP, did the Intel drivers permanently solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intel is providing for some time a special section for Linux drivers for their hardware, and I think you should try the latest **Graphics Installer 1.0.6 for Ubuntu* 14.04, 64-bit** or **Graphics Installer 1.0.6 for Ubuntu* 14.04, 32-bit** which can both be found [on this page](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads).

You might also be interested in other utilities on that page, like **Mesa - 10.2.2** or **Intel-gpu-tools - 1.7**.

I can't promise the Graphics installer for Ubuntu 14.04 will work because I never tested it but since Intel placed it in there, I suppose it should work.

Comment: I've installed graphics installer + mesa-utils package and restarted Xorg. Not sure if anything else needs to be done (I have no idea how this all works together).

Comment: Anything wrong so far? Can you change video settings, do you have opengl enabled, and above all, do you still experience the same issues as before, like screen freezing and so on? Try to play some game and see what happens, and watch videos both online and offline to test your new drivers.

Comment: `glxgears` is working and 1080p big buck bunny is video playing with no problems, I suppose OpenGL is enabled and working. The screen freezing is rare, happens once in about 2-6 days. Will have to wait for it (though I hope it never happens again).

Comment: Screen freezing can also happen when your cpu is overheating. Check your temperatures **sudo apt-get install lm-sensors hddtemp** and you can also install **microcode** package for your CPU. Use [this tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/microcode) for this one.

Comment: Marking this as accepted answer since everything is functioning fine for a few days now :) Temps are stable, the problem must have been in DRM being unable to handle some specific event.

Comment: Glad to hear about it! Thank you for accepting my answer, and please let other guys with similar issues like yours know about it, I mean let them know they can install working drivers by visiting Intel's website with the Graphics Installer 1.0.6 for Ubuntu 14.04. I can only suggest the link, but I cant test those drivers. You can and maybe you'll tell others about it. All the best!