# Intel X4500 + 8GB RAM = no more MTRRs available and X freeze

Tags: 14.04, intel, ram, crash, i915

I have a considerably strange issue with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I have two Lenovo T400 machines - both running the .24 BIOS - with integrated Intel graphics and *two* sets of 2x4GB RAM modules of different brands (Corsair and Samsung) which otherwise work fine.

When I install **either** 8 GB RAM set on **either** machine, I have `dmesg` complaining about `MTRR`:

```
[    0.000000] MTRR default type: uncachable
[    0.000000] MTRR fixed ranges enabled:
...
[    0.757772] vesafb: Truecolor: size=8:8:8:8, shift=24:16:8:0
[    0.757779] mtrr: no more MTRRs available
[    0.757800] vesafb: framebuffer at 0xd0000000, mapped to 0xffffc90004e80000, using 5120k, total 5120k
```

And:

```
[    3.618057] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input8
[    3.618778] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20080730 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[    3.618882] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001028-0x000000000000102F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001000-0x000000000000107F (\_SB_.PCI0.LPC_.PMIO) (20140424/utaddress-254)
[    3.618889] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[    3.619181] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x00000000000011B0-0x00000000000011BF conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001180-0x00000000000011FF (\_SB_.PCI0.LPC_.LPIO) (20140424/utaddress-254)
[    3.619187] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[    3.619189] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001180-0x00000000000011AF conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001180-0x00000000000011FF (\_SB_.PCI0.LPC_.LPIO) (20140424/utaddress-254)
[    3.619193] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
```

What happens next is that after some use (say 4 to 48hrs) and in *no* particular circumstances, is **X completely freezing with the rest of the machine remaining perfectly responsive**, enough for me to `ssh` into it and read `dmesg`:

```
[20931.764148] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[20931.764233] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 3025 at /build/linux-lts-utopic-AIjdaQ/linux-lts-utopic-3.16.0/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/intel_display.c:3324 intel_crtc_wait_for_pending_flips+0x171/0x180 [i915]()
[20931.764238] Modules linked in: nls_utf8 isofs uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops rfcomm videobuf2_core v4l2_common videodev media bnep bluetooth 6lowpan_iphc hid_generic usbhid snd_usb_audio snd_usbmidi_lib hid binfmt_misc uas usb_storage arc4 iwldvm mac80211 joydev pcmcia coretemp kvm_intel kvm serio_raw iwlwifi thinkpad_acpi snd_seq_midi yenta_socket pcmcia_rsrc nvram pcmcia_core snd_seq_midi_event snd_hda_codec_conexant snd_hda_codec_generic lpc_ich cfg80211 snd_hda_intel snd_hda_controller snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep i915 snd_pcm drm_kms_helper mei_me shpchp mei snd_rawmidi snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer drm snd i2c_algo_bit wmi soundcore parport_pc ppdev video lp parport mac_hid firewire_ohci firewire_core ahci psmouse crc_itu_t libahci e1000e ptp pps_core
[20931.764348] CPU: 1 PID: 3025 Comm: Xorg Not tainted 3.16.0-45-generic #60~14.04.1-Ubuntu
[20931.764353] Hardware name: LENOVO 7439AV4/7439AV4, BIOS 7UET94WW (3.24 ) 10/17/2012
[20931.764358]  0000000000000009 ffff88022d99bc10 ffffffff81765ca1 0000000000000000
[20931.764365]  ffff88022d99bc48 ffffffff8106de3d 0000000000000000 ffff880036c99000
[20931.764372]  ffff88022e748238 ffff8800b8a16000 ffff8800b8a16000 ffff88022d99bc58
```

I am at a complete loss here.

What could be happening, besides [the usual X4500 craziness](https://askubuntu.com/questions/527564/why-am-i-experiencing-visual-corruption-with-intel-x4500-graphics-card-on-14-04), and how would I solve it?

Here is [`/var/log/dmesg.0`](http://sprunge.us/JESQ) and the [latter part of `dmesg`](http://sprunge.us/RbPj) copied from the `ssh` session, including the crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

`apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid`

This installs the latest kernel *and* Intel graphics drivers, which do not seem to be affected.